# Not able to install Snowflake connector for Python in Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowsql

I am not able to install connector for Snowflake Python using the below command :

```
python3 -m pip3 install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python
```

Its failing with below error :

> /home/ssg.petsmart.com/nrahman/python3.8.5/bin/python3: No module named pip3

I have the pip3 packages present in lib location of Python3. I do not know why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use if it's the first time you are installing it

```
python3 -m pip install snowflake-connector-python
```

otherwise

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I used below :
python3 -m pip3 install snowflake-connector-python

It failed with error :

/home/ssg.petsmart.com/nrahman/python3.8.5/bin/python3: No module named pip3

Comment: Use `python3 -m pip install snowflake-connector-python` as instructed above

Comment: Hi, I had installed pip3 on my linux machine . I do not have pip.

Comment: pip is a package manager for python packages, if you are using python 3 you have 2 options.        1 : run `pip3 ...` or 2 : run `python3 -m pip ...`   I do not have anything else to add this

Answer (score 0):

Error might be occurring with the version of python. Python version 3.5 is the best stable version for snowflake connector installation. For me below one worked well.

`python3 -m pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python==2.1.1`

for jupyter notebook use

`!pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python==2.1.1 --user`